# SSIS failing to get column value and setting it to NULL

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, netezza

I have an SSIS package that reads data from an Oracle table and puts it into a Netezza table. For some reason, SSIS cannot read a specific column value (2% of the records) as shown in the screenshot here.

[image]

The column type in Oracle is NUMBER(3) and in my Netezza table it's SMALLINT. Any idea why this might be happening?

The error columns do not give me any information either.

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Tried to get a better Error Description using this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345163(v=sql.110).aspx).
2. Reduced batch size from the default 1000, to 100.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

I let it fail and here are the error messages I am getting. I have **4 GB** memory on the my laptop. Could that be an issue?

[DESTINATION_TABLE [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345163(v=sql.110).aspx)] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. SQLExecute returned error while inserting row 35244

[DESTINATION_TABLE [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345163(v=sql.110).aspx)] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: 'HY008'. Native Error Code: 51. Operation canceled

[DESTINATION_TABLE [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345163(v=sql.110).aspx)] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: '01000'. Native Error Code: 1. Unable to write nzlog/bad files

[DESTINATION_TABLE [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345163(v=sql.110).aspx)] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: '01000'. Native Error Code: 1. Unable to write nzlog/bad files

[DESTINATION_TABLE [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345163(v=sql.110).aspx)] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: 'HY000'. Native Error Code: 46. ERROR:  External Table : count of bad input rows reached maxerrors limit

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "DESTINATION_TABLE" (2) failed with error code 0x80004005 while processing input "ODBC Destination Input" (13). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[SOURCE_TABLE [63]] Error: **Failed to add row to output buffer**.

[SOURCE_TABLE [63]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on SOURCE_TABLE returned error code 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: Have you tried just extracting from oracle to a flat file and not using NZ (for troubleshooting). Need to figure out if it's the extract or the load that is causing the problem...

Comment: You should try setting the log directory property of the Netezza destination. You'll at least be able to see the nzlog/nzbad output files so that you have some more information from the destination.

Comment: @NWest - That was a great suggestion. I did that and also had to play with the MaxBufferSize property and changed the commit size from 1000 to 500. It worked but took 2 hours (at downtime) but it took 2 hours to load 646 MB of data. What solved this weird issue was using OLEDB driver for Netezza and doing what Mehtat_90 said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try data conversion in your data flow? Try to convert numeric to (DT_I2)in SSIS and then it shall work I believe

Comment: This solved one part of the problem. It still remains a mystery why 96% of the rows didn't have this weird problem. What solved my issue once and for all was to use DT_12 for that field like you said and OleDB driver for Netezza. I was able to get 100% rows using Oracle->Flat File->Netezza (still using ODBC) but took 2 hours to load 646 MB of data. Using OleDB, it takes under 2 minutes even during the day.

Comment: I believe this issue can be resolved by making AccessMode property to OpenRowset Using FastLoad, or OpenRowset Using FastLoad From Variable.